# Apple APNS and "Entrust Secure CA root certificate"?

Tags: java, apple-push-notifications, certificate

I'm trying to send push notifications to iOS devices.
I've created a developer certificate for the APNS and bonded it with the application identifier.

I then proceeded to use Pushy ( https://github.com/relayrides/pushy ) to establish a connection to the APNS server:

```
final PushManagerFactory<SimpleApnsPushNotification> pushManagerFactory =
        new PushManagerFactory<SimpleApnsPushNotification>(
                ApnsEnvironment.getSandboxEnvironment(),
                PushManagerFactory.createDefaultSSLContext( DEV_CERT_P12__PATH, DEV_CERT_P12__PASSWORD )
                );

final PushManager<SimpleApnsPushNotification> pushManager = pushManagerFactory.buildPushManager();

pushManager.registerFailedConnectionListener(new MyFailedConnectionListener());

pushManager.start();
```

....

```
public static class MyFailedConnectionListener implements FailedConnectionListener<SimpleApnsPushNotification> {

    public void handleFailedConnection(
            final PushManager<? extends SimpleApnsPushNotification> pushManager,
            final Throwable cause) {

        System.out.println("ERROR  -  "+ cause.toString());

        if (cause instanceof SSLHandshakeException) {

            // This is probably a permanent failure, and we should shut down
            // the PushManager.
        }
    }
}
```

I get this error: `javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Received fatal alert: certificate_unknown`.
I'm using the P12 file I've created from the private key of the  certificate I've bonded with the app at developer.apple.com
[image]

After much search I've managed to get some information as to why I can't get this thing to work, in the [Apple Doc](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Chapters/CommunicatingWIthAPS.html):

> Note: To establish a TLS session with APNs, an Entrust Secure CA root
>   certificate must be installed on the provider’s server. If the server
>   is running OS X, this root certificate is already in the keychain. On
>   other systems, the certificate might not be available. You can
>   download this certificate from the Entrust SSL Certificates website.

However, I still have no idea what I'm suppose to do.
I would really appreciate some more specific guidance here.

Thank you.

Comment: How did you create the p12 file? Did you export the certificate+private key from the keytool app?

Comment: I'm on OS X, so I just exported the private key with the Keychain Access.

Comment: I meant the KeyChain Access app (I forgot the name). You are supposed to select both the push certificate and the private key and export them to a p12 file.

Comment: @Eran Still the same error. I've updated the question with the screenshot.

Comment: Are you running your server locally on your Mac?

Comment: @kushyar For development it's on my local Mac, later the code will be deployed on a Redhat.

Comment: @thedp are you using NetBeans?

Comment: @kushyar Eclipse EE, and Java 7.

Comment: Ok. It is hard to tell without seeing your file structure but my guess is that your certificate path might be invalid. which folder did you drop you .p12 in?

Comment: @kushyar I just placed it on the Desktop for a simple dry run. `DEV_CERT_P12__PATH` indicates the correct path, if it was incorrect it gives a different type of error. Or are you talking about that the P12 files MUST be places in some specific location?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I've found the solution. And as the one who suggested it to me, I have no idea why it solved the issue.

Using OpenSSL, I've converted the P12 file (I got from the Keychain Access), to PEM, and from PEM back to the P12...

1. Convert the CER file downloaded from app's APN (at developer.apple.com), to PEM
   `openssl x509 -in aps_development.cer -inform DER -out aps_development.pem -outform PEM`
2. Convert the P12 file created with Keychain Access to PEM
   `openssl pkcs12 -nocerts -in Certificates.p12 -out Certificates.pem`
3. Create a new, GOOD, P12 file
   `openssl pkcs12 -export -inkey Certificates.pem -in aps_development.pem -out GOOD_Certificates.p12`

For more information: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/as3/iphone/WS144092a96ffef7cc-371badff126abc17b1f-7fff.html